# Converter uma string em formato monetário para número e subtrair 90%

Tags: javascript, regex, números

Como posso converter uma string em número e subtrair 90%?

Tentei fazer um código (abaixo), mas ele retorna o valor `3205.5` e não estou conseguindo saber o porquê. Se eu uso o valor `R$ 320,50` funciona.

```js
var a = 'R$ 320,55';

function getMoney (str) {
    return parseInt( str.replace(/[\D]+/g,'') );
}

function formatReal (int) {
  var tmp = int+'';
  tmp = tmp.replace(/([0-9]{2})$/g, ",$1");
  if( tmp.length > 6 )
    tmp = tmp.replace(/([0-9]{3}),([0-9]{2}$)/g, ".$1,$2");

  return tmp;
}

var b = getMoney (a);
var c = b - (b *0.9); 
console.log( formatReal( c ) );
```

Comment: Isso tem mais cara de problema matematico do que de programação em si...

Comment: oi @MarceloBoni ... realmente. Mas dá uma olhada no que está acontecendo... atualizei o post.

Comment: Só pra constar, a regex poderia ser `/\D+/g` - os colchetes são desnecessários neste caso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema está na sua função `getMoney`, que não está convertendo a string numérica (em formato brasileiro) corretamente.

Mais especificamente, o erro se deve a esta expressão regular:

> ```
> /[\D]+/g
> ```

Ela irá dar *match* em **todo** caractere que não for numérico. Isso significa que você também removerá o separador decimal do número (`,`), que é basicamente a mesma coisa de multiplicá-lo por 100. Evidentemente, isso não é o que desejamos.

Para resolver, basta corrigir a expressão regular.

```
/[^\d,]+/g
```

Repare que agora qualquer caractere que não for numérico ou uma vírgula (que é o nosso separador decimal) será removido. Em seguida, precisamos trocar a vírgula (`,` — que é o separador decimal da moeda brasileira) para o ponto (`.` — que é o separador decimal que o JavaScript entende ao fazer o `parseFloat`).

Ficaremos com:

```js
function getMoney(str) {
  return str
    .replace(/[^\d,]+/g, '') // Remove caracteres desnecessários.
    .replace(',', '.');      // Troca o separador decimal (`,` -> `.`)
}

console.log(getMoney('R$ 123.456,89')); // 123456.89
```

Agora podemos calcular a subtração da porcentagem de modo satisfatório:

```js
function getMoney(str) {
  return str.replace(/[^\d,]+/g, '') 
    .replace(',', '.');
}

const a = 'R$ 320,55';
const b = getMoney(a);
const c = b - b * 0.9;

console.log(c);

// Formatando para o formato de moeda brasileira:
const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('pt-BR', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'BRL'
});
const d = formatter.format(c);
console.log(d); // R$ 32,06
```

Como você pode perceber, também não é necessário implementar uma função como `formatReal` na mão, já que o JavaScript já tem APIs de formatação monetária incluídas, tais como [`Intl.NumberFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat) ou [`Number.prototype.toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString).

Comment: Também poderia usar a regex original e dividir por 100 :-)

Comment: @hkotsubo, realmente, nem tinha pensado nisso! :D Boa ideia.

Comment: Muito obrigado pelos esclarecimentos... principalmente na questão da expressão regular !

Answer (score 2):

Você está tendo problemas na hora da formatação (transformar a string para float e depois para string novamente para realizar a operação)

```js
var a = 'R$ 320,55';
/**
* Transforma a string em um float
*/
function getMoney (str)
{
    var valor= str.replace(/[^\d,]/g,''); //remove todos os caracteres menos numeros e virgula
    valor = valor.replace(',','.'); //troca virgula por ponto
    return parseFloat(valor);
}
/**
* Transforma o float de volta pra string com formatação em reais
*/
function formatReal (valor)
{
    return valor.toLocaleString('pt-BR', {style: 'currency', currency: 'BRL'})
}
  var b = getMoney (a);
  var c = b - (b *0.9); 
  console.log(formatReal(c));
```

Dê uma olhada na [documentação de toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)

Comment: oi @Vitor .... Show de bola. Clarrísima a explicação. Muito obrigado... com a toLocaleString tudo fica mais simples,